# Connecting to Database in MS Visual Studio 2010 Error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

When I try to make a connection to a database and error occurs. The message is
"A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to the SQL Server."

The database is located in the App_Data folder of the project.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Need more information; What kind of database is it? What exactly do you mean by 'connecting' to it? In the Servers toolwindow? In an application you are debugging? Do you have the proper server/service running to handle the database? What is the connection string/info you are using? (obfuscate the user/pass, obviously)

Comment: Is your problem happening when your program is run, or while you are using Visual Studio? What exactly is happening when this problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Database in App_Data then most likely a SQL Server Express database. Open SQL Configuration Manager on your local machine and start the SQL Express Service.

Comment: Hi Justin, I am actually running SQL SVR 2008 but brought the database in the app. It was small and just testing it out. For some reason, it kept telling me the db was in use. I rebooted the computer, then it made my connection. Is this a typical thing?